# Use of "("?) in Lua with string.find and the value that it returns

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

```
a, i, c = string.find(s, '"("?)', i + 1)
```

What is role of  `?` here? I believe it was checking for double quotes but I really do not understand exactly the use of `"("?)`.

I read that `string.find` returns the starting and ending index of the matched pattern. But as per above line of code, `a`, `i` and `c`, 3 values are being returned. What is the third value being returned here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` matches an optional character, i.e, zero or one occurrence of a character. So the pattern `"("?)` matches a `"`, followed by an optional `"`, i.e, it matches either `"` or `""`. Note that the match for `"?`(zero or one `"`) is captured.

As for the return value of `string.find()`, from [`string.find()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.find):

> If the pattern has captures, then in a successful match the captured values are also returned, after the two indices.

The capture is the third return value, when there is a successful match.